# VB.NET - What is the 'sender' of BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted?

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I've noticed that there is a `ByVal sender As Object` argument in the `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` handler call and I'm curious as to what the sender would be when a BackgroundWorker completes its work. My gut instinct tells me this would be the BackgroundWorker but there doesn't seem to be any explicit statement on the [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted Event MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) to confirm this. I've also searched SO but I can't seem to find an answer either.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question got me curious:

As per your question, the answer is **YES.**

I tried some testing:

The first one I tried is:

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
       MsgBox(sender.Name.ToString)
    End Sub
```

to know what is the name of the `sender`.

This one is giving me an error.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

But using:

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        If sender Is BackgroundWorker1 Then
            MsgBox("Yeah!")
        End If
    End Sub
```

It prompted `Yeah!`, confirming that the `sender` is the `BackgroundWorker1`.

For your reference: 
[HOW TO: Determine the Sender of an Event Without Using the Control.Name Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457091.aspx)

I hope it enlightened you somehow.

Comment: Your efforts are much appreciated sir :) I shall give the referenced article a read as I'm sure this may help me further!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. :)

Comment: You can also do `MessageBox.Show(sender.GetType().FullName)` to check what type the sender is (i.e. `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`).